# how get products by colors and sizes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

code result: get all sizes and  colors but 
   I want to get products colors and  sizes 
   ex : get products  have small size and color red
   below my code :

```
    $products=Product_property::where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereIN('color',explode(',',$request['colors']));
    })->where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereIN('size',explode(',',$request['colors']));
    });
```

How can solve this problem?
I want to get products colors and  sizes 
ex : get products  have small size and color red

Comment: Please reformat your question. Code goes in the code block, text goes outside. You're currently using the `colors` values for both color and size. More than that, since we have no idea what your `$request`-array looks like or contains, we have no clue how to correctly write your query.

Answer (score 0):

> Followed by your ex: `get products  have small size and color red`
>   Your query should be following:

```
$products = Product_property::where(function ($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('size', '=', $request->size)
         ->where('color', '=', $request->color);
});
```